# Azure Automated Backup Frequency

Tags: sql, database, azure, backup, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Windows VM running a few SQL server databases. Azure premium offers automated backup, which is great. I am however not able to change the frequency of the automated backups, which now occur every 2 hours. These 2 hour scheduled backups result in performance issues when the server is running important SQL Server jobs.

Is there any way to alter the frequency other than creating manual backup jobs with the job agent? Within the Azure portal I can only change things like the backup retention, not the frequency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about Azure SQL or Microsoft SQL in a VM? those 2 are completely unrelated

Comment: Microsoft SQL inside an (Azure) VM.

Comment: that may be due to the IO's occuring during backups.you can change schedule ,so that they won't conflict with your important jobs

Comment: So if it is SQL inside a VM you can control it just like a regular SQL server

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a few options with Windows VMs, including something called the [Windows Backup Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault). This agent allows you to configure redundancy and backup schedule, along with some other properties that may improve your performance.

Another helpful resource I found was [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction) which just talks about planning your back approach, along with next steps after you work through this material.

Answer (score 2):

Try Cloudberry as a backup tool that works with Azure storage. You can set up the backup time and frequency in the way you want it and that is the most comfortable for you. As far as I see it some third-party backup agent is the best option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your MS SQL server inside Azure VM, you can also use native SQL Server backup tools. Hope [this post](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-create-a-sql-server-scheduled-backup/) would be helpful for you.